# Running JQuery scripts on AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using .load() to pull static HTML files onto my main HTML page. The scripts and selectors that I have written exist within:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

But they don't work on the AJAX loaded content. I have read that this is because the selectors that I am using are not available.

Is there a better way to do this? Adding the script to the window.load function doesn't work either:

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

Comment: Just to confirm, your $(document).ready functions are not executing within the .html you are loading into your master page? or the $(document).ready is not locating the elements you are loading via AJAX?

Comment: The latter. There is no $(document).ready in the loaded .html file. Should there be?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    // fire when any Ajax requests complete
})
```

[ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: But that will fire after every AJAX call... which could affect performance, right?  Is there a way to manually trigger the jquery?

Answer (score 3):

There are more than one option:

1. you can add initialization scripts [ `$(this).click...` ] into `callback` function of `$.load()`
2. you can use `$.live()`, which creates handlers even for dynamically loaded/created objects.

**More here**:
callback: http://api.jquery.com/load/ (notice the "`complete()`" function)
bind: http://api.jquery.com/live/

**Edit**: My mistake, it was `live()`, not `bind()`, thank you guys

Comment: I thought it was `$.live()` for dynamically created objects. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I think you mean the `live` function, which is the equivalent of bind, but works for dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind events to dynamically loaded content via jQuery's `$.live()`.

From jQuery http://api.jquery.com/live/:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes an optional callback function argument which you could use to do any setup you need AFTER your ajax-ed content is loaded